# Call a textbox without OnClick on ASP.net web forms

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I'm trying to call a input in my C# code from my html but i dont need to use the OnClick function because i'm handling that with a JS function. I just need to call that input but from C#.

this is on my html:

JS:

```
function valiDate() {
var month = document.getElementById("txmes");
if (month.value > 12 || month.value < 1) {
    month.style.background = "#f28f8f";
    month.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    month.style.borderColor = "#e00000";
    alert("Porfavor ingresa un més valido");
}
```

}

I validated the date and the year on JS , now i need to call this input in a C# function to use it but i dont need OnClick function.

There is some way to do that? Please tell me if im wrong or something like that.

Comment: what does your textbox look like? Are you using `runat="server"`?

Comment: I have that textbox inside a form tag and form is using runat="server"

Comment: Sorry i was wrong, i don't have a TextBox is an Input with the type "text".

Comment: You should be able to add the `runat="server"` attribute to your input and call it by id from the code-behind (C#). In your javascript, you're going to want to alter it a little bit to say: `var month = document.getElementById('<%= txmes.ClientId %>);` since the id will get altered with the runat=server

Comment: Yes!! i added runat="server" to my input tag and it works, Thank you so much.